# Implementing Gibbs sampling in topic modeling using python

Tags: python-2.7, topic-modeling, divide-by-zero

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
```

I encountered this problem when implementing Gibbs sampling of a topic model using python. I need to get the quotient of two arrays in a for loop:

```
result = (self.nas[a, :] + self.gamma)/(self.na[a] + self.Sgama)
```

Both nas and na are numpy arrays with none negative elements. gamma and Sgama are constants, in which gamma = 0.1, Sgama = 2. So both dividend and divisor can not be zero.

I cannot figure out why PyCharm keeps giving this warning all the times. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does the error ever occur when actually running the program? If not, it could just be a PyCharm problem.

Comment: PyCharm keeps giving this warning when running the code. Is there any way to fix it?